# function was not declared (function as argument to another)- XPtr when creating package

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to use a function as argument to another function.

I am building a package.

func1.cpp:

```
    #include <Rcpp.h>
    using namespace Rcpp;

    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
      return x * 2;
    }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x);

typedef NumericVector (*timesTwo_call)(NumericVector x);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<timesTwo_call> putFunPtrInXPtr(std::string fstr) {
    if (fstr == "timesTwo")
        return(XPtr<timesTwo_call>(new timesTwo_call(&timesTwo)));
    else
        return XPtr<timesTwo_call>(R_NilValue); // runtime error as NULL no XPtr
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector testFunc(SEXP func, NumericVector x)
{
    XPtr<timesTwo_call> xpfun(func);
    timesTwo_call fun = *xpfun;

    NumericVector tmp =  fun(x);
    const int N = tmp.size();

    NumericVector result(N);


    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = tmp[i] * 3;
    }

    return result;
}

/*** R
x <- c(1,2,3)
fun <- putFunPtrInXPtr("timesTwo")
result <- testFunc(fun, x)
*/
```

Trying to build , it gives me some errors in the RcppExports.cpp, at line :

`XPtr<timesTwo_call> putFunPtrInXPtr(std::string fstr);`

Errors:

`timesTwo_call was not declared in this scope`
`template argument 1 is invalid`
`template argument 3 is invalid`
`invalid type in declaration before ' token`

-- UPDATE --

I should note that even if I put the definition of `timesTwo` in the main file , I still get the same errors.

But, If (when I put the definition in main) run as sourceCpp, then it works!

-- UPDATE 2 ---

I created the file `test_types.h` under src folder (where all cpp files are).

```
#ifndef TEST_TYPES_H
#define TEST_TYPES_H
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

typedef NumericVector (*timesTwo_call)(NumericVector x);
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x);

#endif
```

but I still get the same errors.

Comment: `sourceCpp()` is meant for _single_ file compilation. You are using _multiple_ files. You must first _build_ the package, _load_ the package, and then _call_ the function. You cannot use `sourceCpp()` for this.

Comment: @coatless:Hi, I am aware of that, I said that I create a package.But, if I try sourceCpp it runs (I wanted to show that code runs ok).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `typedef` is not exported to `RcppExports.cpp`.
See section **2.4. Types in Generated Code** of the [Rcpp attribute vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf). In short: Put the typedef into a header file named:

```
src/<pkg>_types.h
src/<pkg>_types.hpp
inst/include/<pkg>_types.h
inst/include/<pkg>_types.hpp
inst/include/<pkg>.h
```

This file will be automatically included in `RcppExports.cpp`. You have to manually include it in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for helping.I didn't know that was necessary, so I tried it (check updated post) and I still get the same errors..Am I missing something?

Comment: @George Did you call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` before compiling?

Comment: I am building and compiling through Rstudio button.Anyway, I deleted the project, did it again and it works fine!Thanks!(upv)

Comment: @George Most of the time RStudio does the right thing. If it doesn’t "clean & rebuild"(?) sometimes helps.

Comment: Yes, I was pressing clean and rebuild but it wasn't enough though! :)